# How to print out ArrayList of objects vertically in JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

So I'm having problems with printing out my `ArrayList` of objects vertically in `JSP`.

This is my code:

```
 <% ArrayList<Order> list = OrderFacade.retrieveAllOrder(); 
    %>
     <%
                                     for(Order thisorder:list) { 
                                    %>       <%out.println(thisorder.getOrderId());%>
                              <% } %>
```

The output is:

> 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28
>   29

Is there any way that you can print it out in a column rather than a row?

Comment: Insert a <br> after every printed line. This is basic, fundamental HTML. You need to learn the basics.

Comment: The standard way would be to use a <div>...numbers...</div> or a <p>...numbers</p> and style with css. Also use print instead of println. Only insert a line return after the numbers are done.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather a HTML matter here, but anyway you can print a `<br/>` in each iteration or simply wrap each line in a `<div>` it will be automatically diplayed in a new line, so you will get all lines displayed ass a column.:

```
<% ArrayList<Order> list = OrderFacade.retrieveAllOrder(); 
   for(Order thisorder:list) { 
      out.print("<div>"+thisorder.getOrderId()+"</div>"); 
   } 
%>
```

**Note:**

Note that I removed all the useless opening `<%` and closing `%>` tags, you don't need to open and close them in each line, they are only meant to be used to separate `Java` code from `HTML` in `JSP` files.

Comment: Wow **thank you** so much! Sometimes I just get stuck on the stupidest stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job:

```
<% ArrayList<Order> list = OrderFacade.retrieveAllOrder(); %>
    <% for(Order thisorder:list) {                        
        <%out.print("<p>" + thisorder.getOrderId() + "</p>");%>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Welcome to 2002!

Comment: yes, this is old school but it looks like the OP is a beginner.

Comment: Agreed - wasn't intended as criticism, and I would have provided something similar. I would probably have included <%= thisorder.getOrderId() %> rather than out.print() calls.